# Android - Not able to start multiple activities from background

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I am facing a problem.

This is the code I have in my BroadcastReceiver extender class:

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       // other
       Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, ShowMessageActivity.class);
       myIntent.putExtra(Utils.SHOW_MESSAGE_OPTION, messageToDisplay);
       myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       context.startActivity(lockScreenMessage);
    }
```

which starts a new activity when a broadcast is raised.
When the application is in foreground and receives a broadcast, it starts a new Activity as many times as the code executes, but it is not the case when the app is in background. In that case it starts an Activity only once, and not each time a broadcast is received. Why? Is it possible to fix that?

Comment: Generally speaking, it is frowned upon to launch an `Activity` from an background process (in this case, a `BroadcastReceiver` because it interrupts the user. The preferred behaviour is to put a notification in the status bar, so that the user can go to your app to deal with it when he wants to. For this reason, there are restrictions in place to prevent background processes from launching activities. See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts for more info.

Answer (score 0):

that very depends on what do you expect in that receiver, is it any system-side call (declared in manifest) or your own? who an when calls it, thats very important

starting Android 10 there are some restrictions for starting `Activity` from `onReceive`, check out official [DOC](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts). basically you shouldn't start any `Activity` from there, and when it works for you I bet it works only for few secs after `PendingIntent` creation. check out exceptions list under link above, possible reasons would be:

> The app has an activity in the back stack of an existing task on the Recents screen.

> The app has an activity that was started very recently.

> The app called finish() on an activity very recently.

you may check out your code on some emulator with Android 9, all your broadcast calls should work "always"